# How can I use Lighting for specific surface of a 3D object?

Tags: graphics

```
Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{(-0.1 + 10.128)/2, (13 + 1.3)/2, 
     0}, {(-0.1 + 10.128)/2, (13 + 1.3)/2, 0.001}}, 3.2]}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Spot", Red}}]
```

[image]

I would like to use `Lighting` on the top surface of`Cylinder` above to produce the same lighting profile as this one

```
plane = DiscretizeRegion[
   InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], {{-1, 1}, {-1, 
     1}, {0, 1}}, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.01}, 
   BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[], White}];
gty = Show[{plane}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Spot", Red, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {Pi/2, 4}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a very thin cylinder.  [`Ellipsoid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) seems to perform better if you are trying to emulate a disk.

```
cyl = Cylinder[{{(-0.1 + 10.128)/2, (13 + 1.3)/2, 
     0}, {(-0.1 + 10.128)/2, (13 + 1.3)/2, 0.001}}, 3.2];
centroid = RegionCentroid@cyl;
bnds = First@Differences@Transpose@RegionBounds@cyl;
ell = Ellipsoid[centroid, bnds];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 5], Style[ell, c]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Spot", 
     Red, {centroid + {0, 0, 3}, centroid}, θ}}, 
  ImageSize -> Small], {{θ, π/2.5}, π/40, π/2}, {c,
   White, ColorSlider}]
```

[image: ColorSlider manipulate]

The following shows how the image changes at discrete surface colors with constant lighting.

```
Grid[{Graphics3D[{Style[ell, #]}, 
     Lighting -> {{"Spot", Red, {centroid + {0, 0, 3}, centroid}, 
        Pi/2.5}}] & /@ {White, Yellow, LightBlue, Blue}}]
```

[image: Discrete surface colors]

The following shows how the image changes with underlying surface color under a White, Red, Green, and Blue spotlight.

```
mean = First@Mean@Transpose@RegionBounds@cyl;
tt = TranslationTransform /@ (DeleteCases[
        Tuples[{0, #}, 3], {_, _, #}] &@bnds[[1]]*2.5);
ctt = Transpose[{{"White", "Red", "Blue", "Green"}, tt}];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 5], 
   Flatten@({Lighting -> {{"Spot", 
           ToExpression@#[[1]], #[[2]] /@ {centroid + {0, 0, 3}, 
             centroid}, s}}, 
        GeometricTransformation[
         Style[{ell, Text[#[[1]], {mean, bnds[[1]]*2.3, 0}]}, c], #[[
          2]]]} & /@ ctt)}, 
  ViewPoint -> Top], {{s, Pi/5, "Spotlight Angle"}, Pi/20, 
  Pi/2.5}, {{c, Yellow, "Underlying Object Color"}, ColorSlider}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Four Spotlights]

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Tim Laska! Is it possible to assign a specific color for the desk instead of Black?

Comment: @HD2006 The disk is black due to the lack of lighting.  I added the ability to change the surface color through the Style command and specularity if desired.

Comment: it is not working with me, it gives black disk without lighting once I change the color inside style to blue. May you please  let the disk blue while lighting is red as it is and add a picture of the new shape?

Comment: @HD2006 I added a ColorSlider to the Manipulate function to show that the image changes with changes in the surface color.

Comment: but the original color is of the desk is still black, it is not changing, the lighting only does! My question is how can I make the disk e.g. Yellow and lighting is red?

Comment: @HD2006 I am pretty sure the black you are seeing is a function of the lighting.  If evaluate `Graphics3D[{Style[ell, Yellow]}]`, then you should see a `Yellow` disk.  If you add lighting by evaluating `Graphics3D[{Style[ell, Yellow]}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Spot", Red, {centroid + {0, 0, 3}, centroid}, 
    Pi/2.5}}]`, then the disk appears darker because less light is reflecting back.